# C compiler cannot create executables Ubuntu 16.04 gcc v9.3.0

Tags: compiling, gcc, g++

I am trying to run the `./configure` command for the `cmph_2.0` library I downloaded. The gcc and g++ versions are `9.3.0` and I am using Ubuntu 16.04. However, I am getting the below error:

```
   This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.68.  Invocation command line was

  

    $ ./configure --prefix=/~/userB/cmph-2.0
    
    ## --------- ##
    ## Platform. ##
    ## --------- ##
    
    hostname = IIPC121
    uname -m = x86_64
    uname -r = 4.15.0-115-generic
    uname -s = Linux
    uname -v = #116~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 26 17:36:48 UTC 2020
    
    /usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
    /bin/uname -X     = unknown
    
    /bin/arch              = unknown
    /usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
    /usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
    /usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
    /bin/machine           = unknown
    /usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
    /bin/universe          = unknown
    
    PATH: /usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin
    PATH: /usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin
    PATH: /home/userA/bin
    PATH: /home/userA/.local/bin
    PATH: /usr/local/sbin
    PATH: /usr/local/bin
    PATH: /usr/sbin
    PATH: /usr/bin
    PATH: /sbin
    PATH: /bin
    PATH: /usr/games
    PATH: /usr/local/games
    PATH: /snap/bin
    PATH: /home/userA/kaldi/tools/irstlm/bin
    
    
    ## ----------- ##
    ## Core tests. ##
    ## ----------- ##
    
    configure:2367: checking for a BSD-compatible install
    configure:2435: result: /usr/bin/install -c
    configure:2446: checking whether build environment is sane
    configure:2496: result: yes
    configure:2637: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
    configure:2676: result: /bin/mkdir -p
    configure:2689: checking for gawk
    configure:2705: found /usr/bin/gawk
    configure:2716: result: gawk
    configure:2727: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
    configure:2749: result: yes
    configure:2837: checking for gawk
    configure:2864: result: gawk
    configure:2923: checking for gcc
    configure:2939: found /usr/bin/gcc
    configure:2950: result: gcc
    configure:3179: checking for C compiler version
    configure:3188: gcc --version >&5
    gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-23ubuntu1~16.04) 9.3.0
    Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
    warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
    
    configure:3199: $? = 0
    configure:3188: gcc -v >&5
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=gcc
    COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
    OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
    OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
    Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
    Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.3.0-23ubuntu1~16.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-9-oatUX7/gcc-9-9.3.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
    Thread model: posix
    gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-23ubuntu1~16.04) 
    configure:3199: $? = 0
    configure:3188: gcc -V >&5
    gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
    gcc: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.
    configure:3199: $? = 1
    configure:3188: gcc -qversion >&5
    gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
    gcc: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.
    configure:3199: $? = 1
    configure:3219: checking whether the C compiler works
    configure:3241: gcc /include  /lib conftest.c  >&5
    gcc: error: /include: No such file or directory
    configure:3245: $? = 1
    configure:3283: result: no
    configure: failed program was:
    | /* confdefs.h */
    | #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
    | #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
    | #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
    | #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
    | #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
    | #define PACKAGE_URL ""
    | #define PACKAGE "cmph"
    | #define VERSION "2.0"
    | /* end confdefs.h.  */
    | 
    | int
    | main ()
    | {
    | 
    |   ;
    |   return 0;
    | }
    configure:3288: error: in `/home/userA/userB/cmph-2.0':
    configure:3290: error: C compiler cannot create executables
    See `config.log' for more details
    
    ## ---------------- ##
    ## Cache variables. ##
    ## ---------------- ##
    
    ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
    ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
    ac_cv_env_CC_set=
    ac_cv_env_CC_value=
    ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
    ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=/include
    ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
    ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
    ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
    ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
    ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
    ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
    ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
    ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
    ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
    ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=/lib
    ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
    ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
    ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
    ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
    ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
    ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
    ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
    ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
    ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
    ac_cv_path_mkdir=/bin/mkdir
    ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
    ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
    ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
    
    ## ----------------- ##
    ## Output variables. ##
    ## ----------------- ##
    
    ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/userA/userB/cmph-2.0/missing --run aclocal-1.11'
    AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
    AMDEP_FALSE=''
    AMDEP_TRUE=''
    AMTAR='${SHELL} /home/userA/userB/cmph-2.0/missing --run tar'
    AR=''
    AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/userA/userB/cmph-2.0/missing --run autoconf'
    AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/userA/userB/cmph-2.0/missing --run autoheader'
    AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/userA/userB/cmph-2.0/missing --run automake-1.11'
    AWK='gawk'
    CC='gcc'
    CCDEPMODE=''
    CFLAGS='/include'
    CHECK_CFLAGS=''
    CHECK_LIBS=''
    CPP=''
    CPPFLAGS=''
    CXX=''
    CXXCPP=''
    CXXDEPMODE=''
    CXXFLAGS=''
    CXXMPH=''
    CYGPATH_W='echo'
    DEFS=''
    DEPDIR=''
    DLLTOOL=''
    DSYMUTIL=''
    DUMPBIN=''
    ECHO_C=''
    ECHO_N='-n'
    ECHO_T=''
    EGREP=''
    EXEEXT=''
    FGREP=''
    GETCONF=''
    GREP=''
    INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
    INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
    INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
    INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
    LD=''
    LDFLAGS='/lib'
    LIBM=''
    LIBOBJS=''
    LIBS=''
    LIBTOOL=''
    LIPO=''
    LN_S=''
    LTLIBOBJS=''
    MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/userA/userB/cmph-2.0/missing --run makeinfo'
    MANIFEST_TOOL=''
    MKDIR_P='/bin/mkdir -p'
    NM=''
    NMEDIT=''
    OBJDUMP=''
    OBJEXT=''
    OTOOL64=''
    OTOOL=''
    PACKAGE='cmph'
    PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
    PACKAGE_NAME=''
    PACKAGE_STRING=''
    PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
    PACKAGE_URL=''
    PACKAGE_VERSION=''
    PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
    RANLIB=''
    SED=''
    SET_MAKE=''
    SHELL='/bin/bash'
    STRIP=''
    USE_CXXMPH_FALSE=''
    USE_CXXMPH_TRUE=''
    USE_LIBCHECK_FALSE=''
    USE_LIBCHECK_TRUE=''
    VERSION='2.0'
    ac_ct_AR=''
    ac_ct_CC='gcc'
    ac_ct_CXX=''
    ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
    am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
    am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
    am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
    am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
    am__fastdepCXX_FALSE=''
    am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
    am__include=''
    am__isrc=''
    am__leading_dot='.'
    am__quote=''
    am__tar='${AMTAR} chof - "$$tardir"'
    am__untar='${AMTAR} xf -'
    bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
    build=''
    build_alias=''
    build_cpu=''
    build_os=''
    build_vendor=''
    datadir='${datarootdir}'
    datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
    docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
    dvidir='${docdir}'
    exec_prefix='NONE'
    host=''
    host_alias=''
    host_cpu=''
    host_os=''
    host_vendor=''
    htmldir='${docdir}'
    includedir='${prefix}/include'
    infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
    install_sh='${SHELL} /home/userA/userB/cmph-2.0/install-sh'
    libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
    libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
    localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
    localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
    mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
    mkdir_p='/bin/mkdir -p'
    oldincludedir='/usr/include'
    pdfdir='${docdir}'
    prefix='/~/userB/cmph-2.0'
    program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
    psdir='${docdir}'
    sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
    sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
    sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
    target_alias=''
    
    ## ----------- ##
    ## confdefs.h. ##
    ## ----------- ##
    
    /* confdefs.h */
    #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
    #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
    #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
    #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
    #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
    #define PACKAGE_URL ""
    #define PACKAGE "cmph"
    #define VERSION "2.0"
    
    configure: exit 77
```

Comment: I suspect the issue is that you have some inappropriate environment variables set - something like `CFLAGS=/include` and/or `LDFLAGS=/lib`

Comment: @steeldriver And how can i fix that?

Comment: First confirm which variables are causing the issue, then either find where they're being set, and correct them - or unset or unexport them (e.g. if you are using a bash shell, using `export -n` ex. `export -n CFLAGS LDFLAGS`)

Comment: ? How about this cmph-2.0 : `sudo apt install libcmph-dev libcmph-tools` https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cmph&searchon=names ..... Install OK with **Ubuntu 16.04**.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely not really that the C compiler cannot create executables, it's that it cannot create executables *with the parameters given*.

In particular,

```
configure:3241: gcc /include  /lib conftest.c  >&5
```

shows that the configure script is executing the command `gcc /include  /lib conftest.c` which makes no sense: `gcc` treats non-option arguments as source code files. It possibly should have been `gcc -I/include  -L/lib conftest.c` which makes a little more sense, except that `/include` and `/lib` are likely already in the compiler's built-in search paths for include files and libraries respectively (you can confirm that with `gcc --print-search-dirs`).

The arguments get into the configure script as a result of expansion of the autoconf macro `ac_link`

```
ac_link='$CXX -o conftest$ac_exeext $CXXFLAGS $CPPFLAGS $LDFLAGS conftest.$ac_ext $LIBS >&5'
```

where the variables `CXX`, `CXXFLAGS`, `CPPFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS` and `LIBS` will get initialized from environment variables of the same names if they exist. So

- if you are trying to pass values of these variables to the script, then you are doing it wrong and must correct it (for example, adding `-I` in front of `/include` in the value of `CFLAGS`)
- if you are **not** trying to pass values of the variables, then clean them out of your environment altogether, either by unsetting them or unexporting them. In the bash shell, you can do the latter using `export -n` ex. `export -n CFLAGS LDFLAGS` before running the `./configure` script.

Answer (score 2):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17577060/15108576) from [Paul Tomblim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3333/paul-tomblin) did it for me.

> You need to install the perl library for C. If you're on a Debian based system (including Ubuntu) sudo apt-get install libperl-dev or something similar may be sufficient, depending on which version of perl you're using.

Turns out I didn't have that library; I installed it with `sudo apt install libperl-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04, build example **cmph-2.0.2** ... The system compiler is gcc-5 / g++-5 ....... **gcc-9.3.0** was used for building cmph2.

```
$ sudo apt install autoconf libtool
```

`gcc93-c++_9.3.0-16_amd64.deb` → https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xVEATaYAwqvseBzYxKDzJoZ4-Hc_XOJm?usp=sharing

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/cmph/cmph_2.0.2.orig.tar.gz
tar xvf cmph_2.0.2.orig.tar.gz
cd cmph_2.0.2/
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/cmph/cmph_2.0.2-2.debian.tar.xz
tar xvf cmph_2.0.2-2.debian.tar.xz
patch -p1 < debian/patches/stdout_not_stderr.patch
libtoolize && aclocal && autoheader && automake --add-missing && autoconf 
export CC=gcc93 CXX=g++93 && ./configure --prefix=/home/knudfl/tmp1/cmph-2.0.2/usr
make                   ## No errors
make install
```